# Encoding characters in database

Tags: java, jpa, encoding

I need a Polish characters in my web project(Java EE). When I insert a row in database, all ok, but when i try insert row in my page. In database i see ? instead Polish characters. I set a UTF-8 encoding in my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Where else do I need to set something?

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL? MSSQL? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You have to make sure that your connection to your database (from Java) is also using UTF-8 encoding. Also, if you're going to put the charset in the `meta` tag (instead of in an HTTP header where it should be), it must be within the first 512 bytes of the start of the content and before any tags containing text (even before the `title` tag). Otherwise, not all browsers will respect it.

Comment: MySQL is my database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `utf-8` engine to your database. Try as character encoding connection to your database connection.

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

For more sure, You should write `ServetFilter` to set the character encoding type. I think,

CharSetFilter.java

```
public class CharSetFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

web.xml config

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharSet Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.package.CharSetFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharSet Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```